# Is it possible to identify this bottle and its contents?

Tags: spirits, liqueur, identification

[image: alcohol from a Slavic country]

My brother-in-law received this bottle while in a soccer recruit tryout in Yugoslavia(?) around 6ths year 2000. We haven't been able to identify it by anything on the label. It was opened, I think it is brandy but it is beyond its best years. If you look closely it has a wooden cross in the bottle. I have other pictures. I think it could have been made by a monastery. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a couple more images to include the Tapahtobaho (?) label more clearly?

Comment: Is there another label on the back?

Comment: no, there is no label on the back

Comment: please excuse my novice approach to using StackExchange

Answer (score 3):

The label looks like Serbian, and says:

```
Гарантовано природна (garantovano prirodna) = Guaranteed Natural
стара 10 година      (stara 10 godina)      = Aged 10 Years
```

I don't see anything that identifies it further. But if this was offered as a "typical" Yugoslav gift, it might well be barrel-aged plum brandy (slivovitz).